# How to dynamically assign values to object properties in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typeof, keyof

I have these two types:

```
type ArbitraryPropertyName = keyof typeof arbitrary;
type D = { [k in ArbitraryPropertyName]: any };
```

Now I want to declare a variable of `type D`, but I don't want to assign each arbitraryPropertyName one by one, like this:

```
const d: D = {
  arbitraryPropertyName1 = ...,
  arbitraryPropertyName2 = ...,
            ...,
  arbitraryPropertyNameN = ...
}
```

Is there a way to dynamically assign a value to each property ?

Answer (score 0):

In general you cannot go from a `type` to a variable.  In this case the `type ArbitraryPropertyName` comes from a variable `arbitrary` so we can use `Object.keys(arbitrary)` to get all of the names in the `type`.

Creating the object will require some `as` assertion at some point because the `Object` prototype functions `Object.keys` and `Object.entries` use `string` as the type for the keys instead of the specific keys from the object's type.

Here is one way: (requires lib: es2019)

```
const d: D = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.keys(arbitrary).map(
    key => ([key, "some default"])
  )
) as D; // have to assert
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/WJ99km)

You might want to return a more specific type (a subset of `D`) based on the value type.

```
type DMap<T> = { [k in ArbitraryPropertyName]: T };

const makeD = <T extends any>(value: T): DMap<T> => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys(arbitrary).map(
      key => ([key, value])
    )
  ) as DMap<T>;
}

const d = makeD(0); // all values are 0
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/w2668w)